# How to I automate re-compilation of a kernel module on Debian / Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, automation, kernel-module

I have the source for a kernel module which I want to re-compile every time the kernel gets updated - is there a sophisticated way to do this?

Of course I could always compile the module on system startup or you manually compile after each `apt update`. And I already hear some of you suggest to write a `.deb` file for this, but I need this for only one computer and I never did this before so it feels a bit like over-engineering to me..

What I'd really like to see is some kind of hook for a given package which executes a script each time that package has been updated..

Comment: Have a look at [DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support).

Comment: It might even be already available who knows? (`apt-cache search --names-only dkms$`)